# How should I test the functionality of an Android activity containing a ListFragment?

Tags: android, testing

I want to test the functionality of an activity that contains a `ListFragment`, but I am not sure how to go about this. I have tried a lot, but nothing seems to work.

So the activity I want to test contains a `ListFragment`, and this `ListFragment` is populated by using `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks` and a `CursorLoader`. This `CursorLoader` queries a `ContentProvider`, and the `onLoadFinished()` method swaps the `Cursor` into the `ListAdapter` of the `ListView`.

What I want to achieve with my test is to start the activity and then test if the `ListView` is populated with the correct data. Because the content of my `ContentProvider` is based on content retrieved from a webservice with a `Service`, I thought I should mock the `ContentProvider` to ensure the test data is what the test expects. But this is easier said than done. I have run into all sorts of problems.

I believe most problems come from the fact that my data is loaded through an `AsyncTask` by the `CursorLoade`r. I start my loader in the `onCreate()` method of my `ListFragment`, but after `onCreate()` finishes my test executes, because it does not wait for the `AsyncTask` loading to be finished. And because the loading does not finish before the test executes, my test fails.

This is my test class:

```
public class TopscorersActivityTest extends ActivityUnitTestCase<TopscorersActivity> {

    public static final int TEST_POSITION = 1;
    public static final String TEST_NAME = "name";
    public static final String TEST_CLUB = "club";
    public static final int TEST_GOALS = 2;

    private Intent mStartIntent;
    private ListView mListView;
    private Context mContext;
    private ContentResolver mContentResolver;

    public TopscorersActivityTest() {
        super(TopscorersActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        mStartIntent = new Intent();

        mContext = new RenamingDelegatingContext(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(), "test");
        mContentResolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
        setActivityContext(mContext);

        // Setup database fixture
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Topscorers.TOPSCORER_POSITION, TEST_POSITION);
        values.put(Topscorers.TOPSCORER_NAME, TEST_NAME);
        values.put(Topscorers.TOPSCORER_CLUB, TEST_CLUB);
        values.put(Topscorers.TOPSCORER_GOALS, TEST_GOALS);

        mContentResolver.delete(Topscorers.CONTENT_URI, null, null);
        mContentResolver.insert(Topscorers.CONTENT_URI, values);
    }

    public void testPreConditions() {
        startActivity(mStartIntent, null, null);
        assertNotNull(getActivity());

        mListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        assertNotNull(mListView);

        Cursor cursor = mContentResolver.query(Topscorers.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        assertEquals(1, cursor.getCount());
    }

    public void testListPopulatedCorrectly() {
        startActivity(mStartIntent, null, null);
        getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();

        ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        assertEquals(1, listView.getCount());
    }
}
```

The `testPreConditions()` test succeeds, but the `testListPopulatedCorrectly()` fails because `listView.getCount()` returns 0.

How can I achieve what I want? Am I even going in the right direction with my test code? Or should I take another approach? If so, what?

Comment: Nobody? Even some general remarks regarding my testing approach are appreciated right now, because I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I have not received any response on my question, I will answer my own question. I decided to go with another approach than used in the code sample of my question. The basic outline of my new approach is:

- I switched my base test class to ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2
- I created a `MockHttpClient` class, which I inject into my code, and this `MockHttpClient` returns a successful `HttpResponse` with a response entity containing my JSON fixture data. The `MockHttpClient` class implements the `HttpClient` interface and returns `null` for all methods but the `execute()` methods that should return a `HttpResponse` object.
- Because the `ListFragment` I am testing registers a `BroadcastReceiver` to determine that the data retrieval service is finished, I also register a `BroadcastReceiver` in my test. I block my test with a `CountDownLatch` until the broadcast is received.
- When the broadcast is received, I use `Thread.sleep(500)` to let my activity update the `ListView`. After that I run my assertions against the `ListView`.
- I annotated my test with `FlakyTest(tolerance=5)`, which executes the test up to 5 times when assertions fail.

I am not sure if this is a good approach, so please feel free to leave some comments. But for now it works. To conclude my answer, the new code for my test:

**TEST CLASS**

```
public class TopscorersActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<TopscorersActivity> {

    public static final String JSON = "[" 
        +   "{\"position\": 1, \"name\": \"Bas Dost\", \"club\": \"sc Heerenveen\", \"goals\": \"16\" },"
        +   "{\"position\": 2, \"name\": \"Dries Mertens\", \"club\": \"PSV\", \"goals\": \"13\"},"
        +   "{\"position\": 3, \"name\": \"Luuk de Jong\", \"club\": \"FC Twente\", \"goals\": \"12\"}"
        + "]";

    private TopscorersActivity mActivity;
    private ListView mListView;

    public TopscorersActivityTest() {
        super("com.example.package", TopscorersActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        ConnectivityUtils.setHttpClient(MockHttpClient.createInstance(JSON));
        mActivity = getActivity();
        mListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
        ConnectivityUtils.setHttpClient(null);
    }

    @MediumTest
    public void testPreconditions() {
        assertNotNull(mActivity);
        assertNotNull(mListView);
        assertEquals(0, mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
    }

    @FlakyTest(tolerance=5)
    @LargeTest
    public void testListItemsPopulatedCorrectly() throws InterruptedException {
        waitForBroadcast(mActivity, TopscorersService.BROADCAST_ACTION, Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

        assertEquals(3, mListView.getCount());

        // First list item
        View view = mListView.getChildAt(0);
        assertNotNull(view);

        TextView positionTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.topscorerPositionTextView);
        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.topscorerNameTextView);
        TextView goalsTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.topscorerGoalsTextView);

        assertEquals("1", positionTextView.getText());
        assertEquals("16", goalsTextView.getText());
        assertEquals(
            Html.fromHtml("Bas Dost<br /><i>sc Heerenveen</i>").toString(), 
            nameTextView.getText().toString()
        );

        // Second list item
        view = mListView.getChildAt(1);
        assertNotNull(view);

        positionTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.topscorerPositionTextView);
        nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.topscorerNameTextView);
        goalsTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.topscorerGoalsTextView);

        assertEquals("2", positionTextView.getText());
        assertEquals("13", goalsTextView.getText());
        assertEquals(
                Html.fromHtml("Dries Mertens<br /><i>PSV</i>").toString(), 
                nameTextView.getText().toString()
        );

        // Third list item
        view = mListView.getChildAt(2);
        assertNotNull(view);

        positionTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.topscorerPositionTextView);
        nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.topscorerNameTextView);
        goalsTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.topscorerGoalsTextView);

        assertEquals("3", positionTextView.getText());
        assertEquals("12", goalsTextView.getText());
        assertEquals(
                Html.fromHtml("Luuk de Jong<br /><i>FC Twente</i>").toString(), 
                nameTextView.getText().toString()
        );
    }

    private void waitForBroadcast(Context context, String action, String category) throws InterruptedException {
        final CountDownLatch signal = new CountDownLatch(1);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(action);
        intentFilter.addCategory(category);
        BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                signal.countDown();
            }
        };

        context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
        signal.await(1500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        context.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
}
```

**MOCK HTTP CLIENT CLASS**

```
public class MockHttpClient implements HttpClient {
    private HttpResponse mHttpResponse;

    /**
     * A MockHttpClient with an HTTP 1.1 200 OK response
     * 
     * @param response
     * @return
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
     */
    public static HttpClient createInstance(String response) 
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        return createInstance(200, "OK", response);
    }

    /**
     * A MockHttpClient with an HTTP 1.1 response
     * 
     * @param statusCode
     * @param reasonPhrase
     * @param response
     * @return
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
     */
    public static HttpClient createInstance(int statusCode, String reasonPhrase, String response) 
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        return createInstance(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, statusCode, reasonPhrase, response);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param version
     * @param statusCode
     * @param reasonPhrase
     * @param response
     * @return
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
     */
    public static HttpClient createInstance(ProtocolVersion version, int statusCode, String reasonPhrase, String response)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        StatusLine statusLine = new BasicStatusLine(version, statusCode, reasonPhrase);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = new BasicHttpResponse(statusLine);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = new StringEntity(response);
        httpResponse.setEntity(httpEntity);
        return new MockHttpClient(httpResponse);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * 
     * @param httpResponse
     */
    private MockHttpClient(HttpResponse httpResponse) {
        mHttpResponse = httpResponse;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param request
     * @return
     */
    public HttpResponse execute(HttpUriRequest request) {
        return mHttpResponse;
    }

    @Override
    public HttpResponse execute(HttpUriRequest request, HttpContext context)
            throws IOException, ClientProtocolException {
        return mHttpResponse;
    }

    @Override
    public HttpResponse execute(HttpHost target, HttpRequest request)
            throws IOException, ClientProtocolException {
        return mHttpResponse;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T execute(HttpUriRequest arg0,
            ResponseHandler<? extends T> arg1) throws IOException,
            ClientProtocolException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public HttpResponse execute(HttpHost target, HttpRequest request,
            HttpContext context) throws IOException,
            ClientProtocolException {
        return mHttpResponse;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T execute(HttpUriRequest arg0,
            ResponseHandler<? extends T> arg1, HttpContext arg2)
            throws IOException, ClientProtocolException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T execute(HttpHost arg0, HttpRequest arg1,
            ResponseHandler<? extends T> arg2) throws IOException,
            ClientProtocolException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T execute(HttpHost arg0, HttpRequest arg1,
            ResponseHandler<? extends T> arg2, HttpContext arg3)
            throws IOException, ClientProtocolException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ClientConnectionManager getConnectionManager() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public HttpParams getParams() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using a `Thread.wait(500)` call that @Jan-Henk mentioned, in the unit test, I used a [DataSetObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DataSetObserver.html) by doing:

```
mListView.getAdapter().registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            assertTrue(mListView.getCount() > 0);
        }
    });
```

Doing this allows you to get the change exactly when it does.